# Split file using awk at pattern

Tags: linux, awk

Here is an example of the data that I have in a row in example.tsv:

`somedata1:data1#||#somedata2:data2#||#somedata1:data3#||#somedata2:data4`

I wanted to do two things:

1. Split the data from the pattern `'#||#'` and write it to other file. The number of columns after splitting is not fixed.
   I have tried the awk command:

   `awk -F"#\|\|#" '{print;}' example.tsv > splitted.tsv`

   Output of the first file should be:

   `column 1
   somedata1:data1
   somedata2:data2
   somedata1:data3
   somedata2:data4`
2. Next I want split the data in splitted.tsv based on the **':'**.

   `somedata1
     data1
     data3`
   And write it to a file.
   Is there a way we could do this in a single awk command?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output, I don't really understand what you need here. Is the first file necessary? Should the result of the second split also be in separate files or printed to the terminal?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please also show the desired output of the second split. Also, please clarify whether or not you need these to be printed to separate files or just to the standard output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `|` correctly.  Then use `split`

```
awk -F'#\\|\\|#' '{split($2,a,":");print a[2]}' file
data2
```

To print all data out in a table:

```
awk -F'#\\|\\|#' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file
somedata:data1
somedata:data2
somedata:data3
somedata:data1
```

To split the data even more:

```
awk -F'#\\|\\|#' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,":");print a[1],a[2]}}' file
somedata data1
somedata data2
somedata data3
somedata data1
```

Comment: file data2 is? And could you explain the $2 and a too. Thanks.

Comment: For me it doesn't work unless I put three `|`.  `awk -F"#\\\|\\\|#" ...`

Comment: @jas You need different number of back slash "\" if you have single or double quoting for the field separator.

Comment: Zoinks! Thanks, @Jotne, you just solved at least one aspect of years of on-and-off confusion with backslashes.

Comment: to just have the `somedata:data1` what command would be required?

Comment: @Vaulstein The first or last or both?

Comment: @Jotne I need all the splits in a single column. Wait will edit the question

Comment: Good job figuring out the requirements, I still don't understand the question! Oh, and the `delete a` is doing nothing useful as the `split($i,a,":")` will wipe out all previous contents of `a`.

Comment: @EdMorton I did forget to remove `delete a` used under debugging. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For the first split, you could try

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "column1"}{gsub(/#\|\|#/,"\n"); print }' file 
column1
somedata:data1
somedata:data2
somedata:data3
somedata:data1
```

To then split on `:`, you could do:

```
$ awk -F: 'BEGIN{print "column1","column2"}
                {gsub(/#\|\|#/,"\n"); gsub(/:/," ");print }' file
column1 column2
somedata data1
somedata data2
somedata data3
somedata data1
```

Comment: @EdMorton I guess you point is that that will avoid the overhead of converting the string to a regex? Done, anyway.

Comment: My point is really just that it's the correct syntax. It shouldn't be a conscious decision TO use regexp delimiters around a regexp, it should take a conscious decision after some consideration NOT to because there's some specific unusual behavior you need at that point. It's like you should always quote your shell variables because that's the correct thing to do UNLESS you have something specific you want to accomplish by not doing it and understand the caveats/gotchas. In both cases by always using the correct syntax, as a benefit you always get the simplest, most intuitive behavior.